# Wordpress upload path incorrect after site migration

Tags: wordpress, upload

I have recently migrated a Wordpress site all is fine apart from when I try and upload some new media. I get an error message saying that the upload failed because:

The uploaded file could not be moved to /var/www/vhosts/mysite.org.uk/httpdocs/wp-content/uploads.

It appears to be adding /httpdocs/ after the site url which is incorrect. Where is this defined and how can I change it?

Comment: The WordPress codex has a canonical document on moving an install: http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress it shows which settings need changing. This seems weird though, IIRC Wordpress usually autodetects the file paths it needs to function

Comment: Thanks for the reply Pekka I cannot see anything there that refers to my problem all paths in the database check out the blog is functioning correctly apart from this upload issue

Comment: The upload path and full paths are under settings > media

Comment: Thanks David I ended up altering the config file but will scope this out